# Python: How to extract time date specific information from text/nltk_contrib timex.py bug

Tags: python, nltk, temporal

I am new to python.   I am looking for ways to extract/tag the date & time specific information from text
e.g.
1.I will meet you **tomorrow**
2. I had sent it **two weeks** back
3. Waiting for you last **half an hour**

I had found timex from nltk_contrib, however found couple of problems with it
https://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/timex.py

b. Not sure of the Date data type passed to ground(tagged_text, base_date)

c. It deals only with date i.e. granularity at day level.  Cant find expression like next one hour etc.

Thank you for your help

Comment: c) Correct, the library only deals in whole days.

Answer (score 1):

b) The data type that you need to pass to `ground(tagged_text, base_date)` is an instance of the [`datetime.date`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) class which you'd initialize using something like:

```
from datetime import date
base_date = date.today()
```

Comment: @usr3592346 I don't see where you posted the error.

Comment: Thanks, I pressed enter incorrectly. half comment got posted                                           
it straight didnt work I had to change a bit        

now=datetime.date.today()    
basedate = Date(now.year, now.month, now.day) 
it worked.

Now I am looking for something that will work for time.  i.e. an hour ago etc.